# jqGrid - Length of colNames and <> colModel! error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jqgrid

When I use this code below, I am getting "Length of colNames and <> colModel!" error. If isUserGlobal is false, I am  not getting any error. I am using jqGrid-4.5.4

```
receivedColModel.push({name:'NAME', index:'NAME', sortable:true});
receivedColModel.push({name:'SURNAME', index:'SURNAME', sortable:true});
receivedColModel.push({name:'AGE', index:'AGE', sortable:true});
receivedColModel.push({name:'STATUS', index:'STATUS', sortable:true});

receivedColNames.push(messageDictionary['userHistory.NAME']);
receivedColNames.push(messageDictionary['userHistory.SURNAME']);
receivedColNames.push(messageDictionary['userHistory.AGE']);
receivedColNames.push(messageDictionary['userHistory.STATUS']);

if(isUserGlobal == 'true') {
    receivedColModel.push({name:'CITY', index:'CITY', sortable:true});
    receivedColNames.push(messageDictionary['userHistory.CITY']);
}

$('#historyGrid').jqGrid({
     url:'ajax.htm',
     datatype: "json",
     mtype: "POST",
     jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, cell:"", id: "", userdata: "jsonModel", root: "rows" },
     postData:postData,
     colNames:receivedColNames,
     colModel:receivedColModel,
     .
     .
     .
```

By the way, If I don't use colNames as a parameter as shown below, programs works successfuly. I don't understand, Why this situtation happens. Thank you very much.

```
receivedColModel.push({name:'NAME', index:'NAME', sortable:true, label:messageDictionary['userHistory.NAME']});
receivedColModel.push({name:'SURNAME', index:'SURNAME', sortable:true, label:messageDictionary['userHistory.SURNAME']});
receivedColModel.push({name:'AGE', index:'AGE', sortable:true, label:messageDictionary['userHistory.AGE'});
receivedColModel.push({name:'STATUS', index:'STATUS', sortable:true, label:messageDictionary['userHistory.STATUS']});

if(isUserGlobal == 'true') {
    receivedColModel.push({name:'CITY', index:'CITY', sortable:true});
}

$('#historyGrid').jqGrid({
    url:'ajax.htm',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, cell:"", id: "", userdata: "jsonModel", root: "rows" },
    postData:postData,
    colModel:receivedColModel,
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't included *real parameters* of jqGrid. It's clear that you use `receivedColModel` and `receivedColNames` for building `colNames` and colModel`. I guess that the origin of your problem is in the part (in the part which we don't see in the text of your question).

You can don't use `colNames` at all. Instead of that you can specify the column header with respect of `label` property of `colModel`. You will don't have any disadvantages. By the way `index` property isn't required if it's value is the same as the value of `name` property. Default value of `sortable` property is `true` and you can remove `sortable:true` too.

Comment: First code block does not work when if statement is true, but second code block works anyway. I currious about this problem. Thank you for your answer.